# How to add every row to previous row in a loop R

Tags: r, for-loop, rbind

I'm writing a loop in r, the error message come from last line: 
  "Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names "
the last line is trying to retain every row value for every loop round. Thanks everyone.

```
a = 20 # resample times
for (id in unique_index){

  jeep_id <- jeep_boot[which(jeep$index == id),]

  #sample_size is 0.8 of the whole data
  sample_size <- floor((0.8)*length(jeep_id$PR))

  #bootstrap sample means 
  samplemeans = rep(NA, a)

  for (i in 1:a) {

    bootsample.i = sample(jeep_id$PR, sample_size, replace=T)
    samplemeans[i] = mean(bootsample.i)

  }
  #combine mean of 20 sample means and stand dieviation of sample means to be one row
  bootresult_id <- cbind(id, mean(samplemeans), sd(samplemeans))
  #retain every row value for each round looping 
  bootresult <- rbind(bootresult, bootresult_id)
}
```

Comment: Please consider providing some example data (and perhaps the expected result) to work on.  You will get more response by doing that. I can create an example data to test it.  But, it may not mimic the actual dataset you have.

Answer (score 0):

What is in `bootresult` before you start the `for (id in unique_index)` loop?
This part wasn't clear to me, and maybe it depends on how you declare it at first place

Alternativo solution for this is declare it as

```
bootresult <- matrix(nrow = length(unique_index), ncol=3)
```

and replace the last line with

```
bootresult[id, ] <- bootresult_id
```